# Update dataframe column based with value from either row 1 or row 2 based on condition in python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe and want to create a column based on a condition that populates the row with the value of a row in another column.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'parent':[32, 3, 88, 9, 10, 23, 99, 23],
                   'id':[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
                   'flag':[True,True,False,True,False,True,True,True]})
```

I have tried to do this using np.where() but it doesn't update the value row by row but instead replaces all values within the column with the condition that is met.

```
df['res'] = np.where(df['flag'] == True, df['parent'], df['id'])
```

The dataframe I want to create looks as follows:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'parent':[32, 3, 88, 9, 10, 23, 99, 23],
                   'id':[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
                   'flag':[True,True,False,True,False,True,True,True],
                   'res':[32, 3, 3, 9, 5, 23, 99, 23]})
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? I'm new to python, so any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Looks like there's a typo in your command. Change `output` to `df`.

Comment: You have another typo on your code. The 'flag' attribute in the first piece of code has a False on the first position... but on the last piece of code it has a True on the first position.

Comment: Thanks for pointing these out. I made the fixes. Sorry about that,

Comment: Also note that you can simply do `np.where(df['flag'], df['parent'], df['id'])` without the need to specify `df["flag"]==True`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change this:

```
df['res'] = np.where(df['flag'] == True, output['parent'], output['id'])
```

to this:

```
df['res'] = np.where(df['flag'] == True, df['parent'], df['id'])
```

Answer (score 2):

Fix your code change the output to df

```
df['res1'] = np.where(df['flag'] == True, df['parent'], df['id'])
df
Out[176]: 
   parent  id   flag  res  res1
0      32   1   True   32    32
1       3   2   True    3     3
2      88   3  False    3     3
3       9   4   True    9     9
4      10   5  False    5     5
5      23   6   True   23    23
6      99   7   True   99    99
7      23   8   True   23    23
```

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed out, you had a typo in your code. An alternative way the achieve the desired output is to use the `apply` method:

```
df['res'] = df.apply(lambda x : x['parent'] if x['flag'] else x['id'], 1)
```

Or

```
df['res'] = np.where(df['flag'], df['parent'], df['id'])
```

**Output**:

```
   parent  id   flag  res
0      32   1   True   32
1       3   2   True    3
2      88   3  False    3
3       9   4   True    9
4      10   5  False    5
5      23   6   True   23
6      99   7   True   99
7      23   8   True   23
```